# Find repeated attribute patterns in collection of objects

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis, data-mining

I have objects $o_1,...,o_k$where every object has a set of properties $p_1,...,p_j$. I'm looking for property *patterns* that are repeated among these objects. It could be perhaps called *correlation* of properties.

Expected output:

$\{p_2,p_4,p_7\}$ present in objects $\{o_2,o_6,o_{12}\}$... and all property patterns with at least two properties.

It will be common to have about $20-30$ properties on every object and hundreds/thousands of objects.

I'm definitely not a math expert but if you tell me what kind of algorithm/what data structures can be best used for this kind of stuff (or even if this problem has a well known name) then I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You may also consider asking at [stats.SE], where **data mining** (the general name for the kind of thing you want to do) is more in focus than it is here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok, thanks for letting me know.